# What does "on the couch" mean?

Tags: american-english, phrase-meaning

What does this mean ?

I'm on the couch tonight for sure

From the movie Judgment Night (1993).

Comment: Without more context, this is hard to tell. Basically, someone says that they are quite confident about the fact they will be on a comfortable piece of furniture in the evening time. On the other hand, they might mean they are going to see a psychiatrist, or that they will be watching a show or movie on TV.

Comment: My guess, with no knowledge of the film, would be that the speaker is saying that they've pissed their partner off in some way and isn't expecting to be welcome in their shared bed tonight.

Answer (score 6):

The usual interpretation, I think, would be "I'm going to be sleeping on the couch tonight". This means that the person's partner will not allow them to sleep in their shared bed, because they have done something wrong or because they are somehow unacceptable as a bed partner (they are drunk, they smell bad, or anything like that!)

Without more context, I can't be entirely sure that this is what is meant, but I think it would be the most common use of this phrase.

Comment: An identical phrase would be "I'll be [sleeping] in the doghouse tonight".